# Insert MathType Equation is disabled in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I am running Numbers 3.1. When I try to select the Insert > MathType Equation... option, it is disabled.

There doesn't seem to be anything in the help related to this feature.

How can I use this menu option?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure the MathType application is running before you invoke the Insert > MathType Equation option. I read about it [here](http://news.dessci.com/2013/11/apple-pages-keynote-and-numbers-software-is-now-free-but-are-they-useful-for-math.html) and tested it on a Mavericks Mac at work a few minutes ago.